# why doesn't it show in Jtable? i am trying to connect my database to my jtable

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jtable

I can't see why this is broken I checked the url and user and password
here is my database properties
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1iNe.png)
nothing wrong with the sql
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6xny.png)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        //conneting my database
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","sisidodo30");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        //the sql code
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM \"SYSTEM\".STOCKSTABLEPROJECT";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        
        while(rs.next()){
            //for some reason it doesn't get in here
            System.out.println("i am in the loop");
            String Name = rs.getString("NAME");
            String Price = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("PRICETODAY"));
            String tbdata[] ={Name,Price};
            DefaultTableModel tblModel =(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
            tblModel.addRow(tbdata);
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if it doesn't enter the loop, then because resultset it empty. So something is wrong with the SQL. Do you get an exception?

Comment: nope only what i get is oracle.jdbc.oracledriver

Comment: just added a picture

Comment: `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` don't do this. Use `e.printStacktrace();` then you will get the proper exception

Comment: I assume that you are not having the proper dependency in your classpath, hence `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` can't be found

Comment: hmm maybe i send my properties of the database with a picture of it right now
and when i tried to change it to print stacktrace it gave me this
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4e73e410

Comment: Do you have this: `catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`?

Comment: ohh damm i wrote 'get' not 'print'
when i tried writing it now it tells me void type not allowed here

Comment: You are still having `System.out.println` I guess?

Comment: ohh damm i am really stupid 
here is the report it shows 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
there is more but i can't send all of it how do i fix it?

Comment: Add the required dependency to the classpath

Comment: Oracle Thin (3) this is the driver name 
how do i write it in the forname?

Comment: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver and this is the class name of the database